# Nanosecond-level C++ program idling / throttling

Tags: c++, multithreading, emulation

I'm writing a C++ program that runs a microcontroller emulator. The thread that runs the emulator does so in a loop like this:

```cpp
while(should_run) {
  simulator->RunSingleClockCycle();
}
```

On my laptop this manages to run the emulator at around 60 MHz. Since I only need the emulator to run at 16MHz, I can slow it down using a busyloop within this while loop so that it runs at 16MHz, since sleeping for a new nanoseconds is not possible.

Since this thread is running the emulator and busylooping, it causes 100% CPU usage on one of my cores. If there was a way to somehow throttle the thread so it runs the microcontroller at 16MHz (without busylooping), it would reduce resource usage for the emulator.

Is there any semi cross-platform (macos + linux) way of achieving this kind of thread throttling in C++?

Comment: Note: It is impossible to get nanosecond timing on conventional PC hardware. You're lucky to get much better than millisecond timing because they're just not built for it. The busy loop is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On conventional hardware you're never going to get nanosecond timing. For example, on my system running this code (not taking into account the race condition):

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>



int main()
{
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    auto res = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            std::cout << "Count : " << counter << '\n';
            counter = 0;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    });


    auto timetoWait = 1'000'000'000 / 16'000'000;
    while (true)
    {
        ++counter;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(timetoWait));
    }
}
```

I get a max of 600-700k "operations" per second. Far from the 16 million the emulator should run at.

You're best off just going with busy looping.

Answer (score 0):

you may use chrono for this purpose, i'm pretty sure it works on both linux and windows.

i'm not aware of any way to measure time that is 100% accurate. these chrono calls some time themselves, but they're relatively accurate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

bool wait(long long nanoseconds)
{
    // if the number of ns to wait is not zero
    if(0 != nanoseconds)
    {
        // init high resolution clock
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock                              hrc             = {};
        // get the start and stop timepoints
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>     start           = hrc.now(),
                                                                        stop            = hrc.now();
        // calculate the number of ns passed by subtracting the time at the start from the time at the stop
        std::chrono::nanoseconds                                        time_passed     = stop - start;

        // while the number of ns to wait for is bigger than the number of ns passed
        while(nanoseconds > time_passed.count())
        {
            // get the new stop timepoint
            stop            = hrc.now();
            // calculate the new number of ns passed
            time_passed     = stop - start;
        }

        // the wait has ended
        return true;
    }

    // the function failed
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    printf("start\n");
    // wait for 5 seconds
    wait(5000000000);
    printf("stop\n");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

you could also use the rdtsc instruction for more accuracy, but i have not been able to make the example code work, so i'll just post it anyways.

here's the assembly code (my IDE, Visual Studio, does not support inline assembly on x64 so i had to write it separately)

```
.model flat, c

.code

get_curr_cycle proc
cpuid
cpuid
cpuid
rdtsc
shl edx, 32
or edx, eax
mov eax, edx
retn
get_curr_cycle endp

end
```

here's the c++ code.

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" unsigned int get_curr_cycle();

bool wait(long long nanoseconds)
{
    if(0 != nanoseconds)
    {
        unsigned int    start           = get_curr_cycle(),
                        stop            = get_curr_cycle();
        unsigned int    time_passed     = (stop - start);

        while(nanoseconds > time_passed)
        {
            stop            = get_curr_cycle();
            time_passed     = (stop - start);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    printf("start\n");
    // wait for 5 seconds
    wait(5000000000);
    printf("stop\n");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while` will still cause 100% CPU load, which OP wants to avoid.

Comment: i am a bit confused by OPs issue i suppose. could OP perhaps use SetThreadAffinity to help run things more smoothly?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you may be looking for is something like

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1));
```

See also:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration

Comment: In reality the OS will not actually sleep for a nanosecond here, rather a time slice which is likely tens of ms. The guarantee for slee_for(x) is that it will sleep for "at least" x

Comment: @Conor I know. But it's as close as you can get `std::` wise.